# How to indent a DIV?

Tags: css, html, indentation

I have a `div` center-aligned with its margin sets to `0 auto`. Now I want to indent its left margin by 50 pixels from the middle. Whenever I try to do this, though, it aligns the `div` to the left side of its container and loses the center align. I think it's because it overrides the left field of the margin property. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? For clarification I want to indent it 50 additional pixels from the center of the container.

Comment: I think you'll need to wrap everything inside that with another container.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

wrap it in another div. make the outer div `margin: 0 auto;` and the inner div `margin-left: 50px`

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To help with responsive web design, I use percentages rather than pixels. margin-left: 5%

Comment: if the div doesn't have a specified width it will be responsive even if the margin is set in px

Answer (score 7):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        #outer {
            margin: 0 auto; /*center*/
            width:200px;
            background-color:red; /*just to display the example*/
        }

        #inner {
            /*move the whole container 50px to the left side*/
            margin-left:-50px; 
            margin-right:50px;
            /*or move the whole container 50px to the right side*/
            /*
            margin-left:50px; 
            margin-right:-50px;
            */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        This is the result!
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
padding-left: 50px;
```

and if that doesn't suffice keep the padding and ad another div inside the bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap another div around your div. Then center align the new div and then margin left or padding left your original div.